# Soundcloud Streaming on Safari Mobile

Tags: streaming, soundcloud

I tried to use this snippet from the Soundcloud API:

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js">
<script>
SC.initialize({
client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

# stream track id 293
SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
 sound.play();
});
</script>
```

It works in any browsers aside from Safari mobile, both on iPhone and iPad, where the  music stream does not play at all.

What am I doing wrong? (I replaced track id and client id with my own details)

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In mobile safari the play has the restriction that audio playback has to be triggered by a user action. So you'll have to add some sort of button or link which when clicked will call the sound.play() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is work around for this issue. What you need to add extra html element.

```
<div class="player-helper"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
SC.stream('/tracks/' + id, {
  useHTML5Audio: true,
  debugMode: true
}, function(sound) {
  let $eventEmitter = $('.player-helper');

  $eventEmitter.on('click', function () {
    sound.play();
  });
  $eventEmitter.trigger('click');
  $eventEmitter.off('click');
});
```

Comment: you need a bracket } here sound.play(); }  );

Comment: this doesn't work on safari mobile, any other suggestions? thanks. Instead of adding a div section, it should work the same with a button, right?